# Array Get Value in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, array

**i want to get profile id from this array**

```
[2019-05-21 07:30:24] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-7KH42411WM009054M',
    'AMT' => 5997.0,
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Year',
    'PROFILESTARTDATE' => '2019-05-28 07:30:22',
    'DESC' => 'Master Subscription',
    'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => '1',
    'METHOD' => 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'PROFILEID' => 'I-M95NGSXREWAC',
    'PROFILESTATUS' => 'ActiveProfile',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-05-21T07:30:24Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => 'f61750cc16cac',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '000000',
  ),
)
```

Comment: please attach code where you get this array value

Comment: public function callCreateRecurringPaymentsProfile()
    {
        $request = $this->_exportToRequest($this->_createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest);
        $this->_exportLineItemsSubs($request);
        $response = $this->call('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $request);
        //$logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        //$logger->debug(print_r("profile status". $response["response"],true));
        $this->_importFromResponse($this->_createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse, $response);
    }

Comment: actually i want to save profile id value in payment additonal

Comment: get this array in $response["response"]?

Comment: $response =  $api->callCreateRecurringPaymentsProfile(); i am calling this funciton

Comment: and doing this but notiing in log $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
                $logger->debug(print_r("testsdfsdf". $response[0]['response']['PROFILEID'],true));

Comment: @werwer : just try my soln once

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: yes plz need urgent

Comment: $response["response"]["PROFILEID"] or $response->getProfileId()

Comment: i also did this but nothing

Comment: @werwer use this:

$logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'); $logger->debug(print_r( $response[0]['response']['PROFILEID'],true));

remove string from print_r syntax.

Comment: what sytax can u write correct code here

Comment: @werwer i just removed 'testsdfsdf' from your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

if you get above array everytime in same format, then you can use below code for to get **PROFILEID**.

```
$arr = $api->callCreateRecurringPaymentsProfile();
if(isset($arr[0]['response']['PROFILEID']) && strlen($arr[0]['response']['PROFILEID']) > 0){
     echo "proFile_id:".$arr[0]['response']['PROFILEID'];
}
```

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/framework/array-manager/

```
$this->arrayManager->get($path, $yourArray)
```